# Как прочитать матрицу из файла (java)?

Tags: java

Интересует чтение матрицы и ее запись в два arrays. Нужно считать размерность матрицы. Потом коэффициенты матрицы 3х3. Потом правую часть СЛАУ в отдельный array.

пример

3

1 1 2 9

2 4 -3 1

3 6 -5 0

Comment: я знаю только как ее напечатать в консоли for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

Comment: интересует самые простые способы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего формата файла можно использовать подобный код:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/file"));
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int[][] x = new int[n][n]; // коэффициенты перед x
int[] a = new int[n];      // правая часть
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        x[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает, а вы знаете как вывести массив в файл?